# Symfony2 can't get date widget to work

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a user object with a birthday column:

```
/**
 * Birthday
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
 */
protected $birthday;
```

In the registration form i add the birthday widget as followed:

```
->add('birthday', 'birthday')
```

But when I send the form, I get `This value is not valid` error for that field.
I've tried some alternatives, but none of them worked:

```
->add('birthday', 'date')
->add('birthday', 'date', array('input' => 'string'))
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What did you input to get such a message? Have you tried to play with the `format` option?

Comment: The widget is of "choice" widget, so i just leave the 3 dropdown boxes with their default values (1-1-2007). I also tried to play with the `format` option - didn't work. Plus, I don't even have a constraint for that field, so what throws that error?

Comment: You don't need to set a constraint, since you're using the DateType type, symfony knows you are supposed to provide a date. And I think the `format` option must be incompatible with the default widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dumb mistake..!!

My timezone settings in php.ini was invalid which caused the date transformer to throw an exception

Answer (score 2):

In you want to insert string as input into a date field, you should use the option : 'widget' => 'single_text'

```
$builder->add('date_created', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'YYYY-MM-dd',
));
```

Comment: but I don't, I want to use the "choice" widget style, it just won't work